# Loop data in Cython's string

Tags: python, casting, boolean, cython

I have a `string` data-type variable `x`:

```py
print(x)

>>> b'011010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000011101110110111101110010011011000110010000001010'
```

and I'm doing this

```py
cdef int data
for data in x:
        print(data)


>>> 48
    49
    49
    48
    49

etc...
```

Why `48` and `49`? Is it because this data are `bytes` because of c++'s `cdef string`?

I would like to have something like

```py
cdef int data
for data in x:
        print(data)


>>> 0
    1
    1
    0
    1

etc...
```

How should I do it? Btw. I want to cast this `0/1` to `list` (or `vector[bool]`) of `False/True` next in my code. If it could be possible ...Thanks

Something like this in normal Python

```py
for data in x:
    final_list.append(bool(int(data)))

print(final_list)
>>> [False, True, True etc...] # 0 = False, 1 = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Cython, but this is the expected behavior of the bytes object for standard Python programs. The bytestring `b'012'` has three entries. The first is not a zero byte; it's the ascii code for the digit 0. Likewise with the other bytes.

To make the bytes actually be zeros and ones, you could do something like this:

```py
>>> a = b'0110'.replace(b'0', b'\x00').replace(b'1', b'\x01')
>>> a
b'\x00\x01\x01\x00'
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

This is how you can escape the hex byte values for 0 and 1, with `\x00` and `\x01`.

Answer (score 1):

x is in byte format. So convert it in string and then iterate

```
x= b'011010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000011101110110111101110010011011000110010000001010'
y=x.decode("utf-8") 

for b in y:
    print(b)
```